# Возможно ли найти порядок точек полигона?

Tags: математика

У меня есть любой объект в .stl файле. Я нашел точки пересечения объекта с плоскостью, которая указывается пользователем, но есть проблема: Порядок точек не последовательный, а вразброс. Данные нужны для того, чтоб заполнить полигон треугольниками (триангуляция).
Возможно ли найти их порядок, если нет, то как правильно найти последовательно точки пересечения объекта и плоскости ?

*Пример1:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Левый квадрат - моя индексация точек, а правый - индексация, которая мне нужна.

*Пример2:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Фигура может быть любой формы)

Comment: Это трехмерный объект? Как он задан?

Comment: @Igor объект берется из ascii stl файла (объект объемный). 
Я "разрезаю" его плоскостью и нахожу точки, которые лежат на плоскости.

Comment: Если у тебя есть только неупорядоченное множество точек, то откуда ты знаешь, что фигура в «Примере 2» будет выглядеть именно так, а не просто выпуклый многоугольник «15324»... другим словами тебе нужно менять алгоритм поиска пересечений, чтобы он выдавал отрезки, а не точки...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точки, которые Вы нашли, принадлежат граням (и ребрам) объекта. (Вы их, собственно, и находили, пересекая эти грани с заданной плоскостью.) Каждое ребро соединяет две грани. То есть каждая Ваша точка имеет двух соседей, принадлежащих граням, соединенных ребром, на котором эта точка лежит.

> Как бы вы искали эти точки ?

Смотрите. Там идут грани трехмерного тела, заданные тройками точек. Три точки задают плоскость. Вам нужно найти пересечение этой грани-плоскости с заданной плоскостью - отрезок (то есть две точки), если такое пересечение есть. У Вас получится набор таких отрезков. Они должны составлять замкнутый полигон. Эти отрезки можно соединить, находя следующий с одним из концов, совпадающим с одним из концов предыдущего. Вот и получится последовательность точек полигона.

Comment: как я знаю, то для триангуляция нужны последовательный порядок точек. И если пример1 , как я понямию, правильно "протриангулируется", то пример второй - нет

Comment: @ANGRYSHARKknyaz2000 Правильно. Поэтому надо упорядочить точки полигона. Вы знаете каким граням объекта принадлежит каждая точка?

Comment: знаю, но я делаю так:
1) беру каждую точку с stl файла
 2) если ее длина до плоскости = 0, то добавляю ее в std::list  и выходит, что уже не знаю)

Comment: @ANGRYSHARKknyaz2000 Я не знаю, что такое stl файл, но кажется, это неправильно :(.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0) 

Как бы вы искали эти точки ?